# SQL: Multiple Where Conditions

Tags: sql, where-clause, data-manipulation

I want to select the following rows from my table if either of the following conditions are met:

- Condition 1: var_1 can not equal 1 or 0
- Condition 2: var_2 can not equal 2

For example, this means that the resulting table can have var_2 = 2 provided that var_1 <> 1,0. The same way, var_1 can be equal to 1 or 0, provided that var_2 <>2.

I tried to write the following SQL command:

```
select * from my_table where( ("var_1" <> 1 AND "var_1" <> 0 ) OR ("var_2" <>2 ) )p;
```

However, this is returning rows that violate this condition, for example:

```
  var_1 var_2
1     1     2
2     0     2
```

Can someone please show me how to correct this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just do `where var1 > 1 AND var2 != 2` -- not perfect clauses, I don't know if you can have less than 0 for var1, but you should be able to adapt that

Comment: I doubt the above query returns the specified result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the  characters enclosed within double quotes are string literals, so don't specify the column within double quotes.

```
select * from my_table where( (var_1 <> 1 AND var_1 <> 0 ) OR (var_2 <>2 ) );
```

Comment: No, double-quoted texts _are_ object names according to the SQL standard. Single-quoted  texts are string literals. However this depends on the RDBMS as not all of them follow the standard.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm yeah i agree

Comment: And var_1 and var_2 are _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @jarlh I will correct that.